# If there is only 1 partition in an Athena table, but a user doesn't query by that partition, how much data is scanned?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

Let's say I have an Athena table `mytable` partitioned by columns `A, B, and C`.

We will insert data into the s3 bucket from an unload query. The data will be partitioned by `A/B/C`. There will be different values for each.

We want the table to only point to 1 partition for `C`. The way we are thinking of doing this is each time we introduce a new value of `C`, we will

`ALTER TABLE mytable DROP PARTITION (A = 'some A value', B = 'some B value')`

`ALTER TABLE mytable ADD PARTITION (A = 'some A value', B = 'some B value', C = 'new C value')`

Let's say there are 10 different values for C for a given A/B combo.

```
A=A1/B=B1/C=C1/
A=A1/B=B1/C=C2/
A=A1/B=B1/C=C3/
A=A1/B=B1/C=C4/
...
```

If I query `mytable` on only A and B, and `mytable` is only looking at 1 partition, would Athena still scan across `C2, C3, C4`? The query I would run is

```
SELECT ...
FROM mytable
WHERE A = <some A value>
and B = <some B value>
```

I would not query by `C`, so I want to make sure Athena does not scan over multiple C partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Athena would scan all the partition of C like C1, C2, C3, C4  unless you don't filter the partition of C in where condition.

If you don't write the query something like this

```
select * from table 
      where A = <some A value> and 
            B = <some B value> and 
            C = <some C value >
```

If you write like this

```
select * from table 
   where A = <some A value> and 
         B = <some B value>
```

It would scan all the partitions of C.

Comment: Even if mytable is only pointing to 1 partition of C? Then is Alter Table even altering anything?

Comment: @JeremyFisher So each time you will be having only one partition of C in your table, is that what you are saying?